# Action<T,U> and 'T -> 'U -> unit conversion

Tags: f#

In F#, when calling a C# method which takes a `Action<T,U>` as argument, I had thought I should use something like `(fun (x, y) -> ())`. But actually it only accepts `(fun x y -> ())`

Why the former fails? It acts more like the target delegate.

What actually happens when providing a FSharpFun to a method that takes Delegate. It doesn't seem an implicit upcast is performed, as Delegate is not interface or base class of FSharpFun.

Is it an implicit conversion? But I thought F# only does explicit conversion.

Comment: Did you have a look at the spec at the section 8.13.7 ? I think it explains that kind of conversions there.

Comment: @Gustavo do I have to dig into the spec? I had expected this kind of info is available in MSDN sites or easily searchable.

Comment: Well, IMHO for these cases the F# spec is the best reference, and note that some features changes with newer F# versions, so pick the right spec according to your version of F#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument list of a delegate is not a tuple. If F# were to allow `new Action<_,_>(fun (_, _) -> ())` (**invalid code**), this would be no less arbitrary. If this were allowed, an F# function taking a tuple to unit would be converted to a CLI delegate with two parameters and void return type. In actual F#, as you said, the valid form is to provide a function with two curried parameters and unit output.

You could make a delegate that takes a tuple as input, but that has a different signature (and is neither optimal for interop, nor for use within F#):

```
type MyDelegate = delegate of (int * int) -> unit
new MyDelegate(fun (a, b) -> ())
```

To see how exactly F# handles delegate construction, see the F# specification 3.0, Section 8.13.7 at "first type-directed conversion" *(or Section 14.4)*. *Gustavo also pointed this out in the question's comments.* I quote:

> Given:
>
> - A formal parameter of delegate type D
> - An actual argument farg of known type ty_1 -> ... -> ty_n -> rty
> - Precisely n arguments to the Invoke method of delegate type D
>
> Then:
>
> - The parameter is interpreted as if it were written:
>   new D(fun $arg_1$ ... arg_n -> farg arg_1 ... arg_n )

The last line is an object construction expression. These are handled in Section 6.4.2, which basically states that the arguments for delegate construction should be supplied in curried form.